# Barplot with top N items and one bin for the remaining items

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, seaborn

I want to plot frequency of items in a dataframe column. What I currently have is the following:

```
cnt_srs = df['item_code'].value_counts().head(N) ## Top N elements
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.barplot(cnt_srs.index, cnt_srs.values, alpha=0.8, color=color[7])
plt.ylabel('Number of Occurrences', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Item Code', fontsize=12)
plt.xticks(rotation='vertical')
plt.suptitle('Top 40 Items', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

This basically plots the No. of occurrences of top N elements. See the plot below for Top 15 Items.
[image]

What I want to do:

Plot Top N elements + Plot another bar for the remaining Elements.
For visualization see the plot below.[image]

Kindly help me out, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is one possible way of doing it.

```
listy = list()
listy.append(df['item_code'].value_counts()[N:].agg('sum'))
othr_srs = pd.Series(listy[0], index=['others'])
cnt_srs = cnt_srs.append(othr_srs)
```

I have just summed up the remaining counts in the dataframe column and created a separate series for that, then just joined the two series.

There might be a simpler way of doing that but this what I have come up with.